# Mojarra 2.1.6 not working as expected with OmniFaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra, omnifaces

My environment is:

- JDK 6u31
- GlassFish 3.1.2.2
- Mojarra 2.1.6 (bundled with GF)
- PrimeFaces 4.0
- OmniFaces 1.6.3

I configured both [FacesExceptionFilter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter) and [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) for my application, and they work fine for all kinds of exceptions, except `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`. If I invalidate the session and then click a button, the error page for a `RuntimeException` is shown, after the following exception is thrown:

```java
INFO: Session invalidated
SEVERE: FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/WEB-INF/errorpages/errorpage.xhtml' will be shown.java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1560)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$2.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1590)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:254)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.RestorableViewHandler.restoreView(RestorableViewHandler.java:66)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:464)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:253)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

`web.xml`:

```xml
<!-- Servlets and filters. -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Welcome files, error pages and mime types. -->

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/expired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/errorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/403.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

View:

```xml
<h:form id="form" prependId="false">
    <p:commandButton id="invalidate" value="Invalidate" ajax="true"
        action="#{errorTester.invalidate}" />

    <p:commandButton id="btn" value="BOOM" ajax="true"
        action="#{errorTester.btn}" />
</h:form>
```

Bean methods:

```java
public void invalidate() {
    Faces.invalidateSession();
    System.out.println("Session invalidated");
}

public void btn() {
    System.out.println("btn");
}
```

Am I missing something? What could be the problem?

**Note** the same thing works fine with [MyFaces 2.1.13](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/myfaces/binaries/myfaces-core-assembly-2.1.13-bin.zip), so I will just continue with that for now. The other problem I have is with MyFaces, I cannot make PF link or button work from the error page if the view was expired, tried both `?faces-redirect=true` and `Faces.redirect();`.

Comment: I also experienced some problems with Primefaces 4 and JSF 2.1. I you can, I would recommend to try with Mojarra 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not related to the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`. Even without it, you would still keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` during restore view. This is recognizable as a state saving bug of the old Mojarra version. You need to upgrade it (or to switch to MyFaces). [It's currently already at 2.1.26](http://javaserverfaces.java.net). Upgrading should be a matter of replacing the `glassfish/modules/javax.faces.jar` file in GlassFish side.

Comment: I updated to 2.1.26, but I still had the problem. In this case I've found MyFaces a better choice anyways, because this way the JSF library is inserted on the project level instead of the AS level. Definitely reduces headache when deploying the app to different servers :)