# Primefaces with Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

Im using Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler and nearly everything is working fine. 
I am using a template to show the errorpage in my normal interface/design with all menues etc.
When an exception occured and the errorpage is visible - all "p:commandLink"s of my navigation are not working anymore.

CommandLink example of my Template:

```
    <p:commandLink
       action="/user/myModels.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
       actionListener="#{myBacking.switchModel(1)}">
       <i class="fa fa-road fa-fw"></i> #{msgs['user.action.create']}
    </p:commandLink>
```

ErrorPage:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/main_template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:em="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/customcomponents"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <ui:define name="contentWrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-ambulance fa-7x"></i><p:outputLabel value="#{msgs['error.anyError']}"/>
    </ui:define>


</ui:composition>
```

When I click on that commandlink an ajax request is sent but nothing happened.
When I replace p:commandLink with h:commandLink the errorpage is reloaded and after reload has finished the h:commandLink is working properly. So I need to click two times on h:commandLink to get to /user/myModels.xhtml.

Does someone know what could be the problem?

BR and ty in advanced

Comment: I can think of 2 possible causes. To exclude one and other, try adding `<h:outputScript library="omnifaces" name="fixviewstate.js" target="head" />` to `<h:body>` of your main template. In any case, please tell exact JSF impl/version used.

Comment: @BalusC, thank you. including this script solved another issue I had with my session/login. Unfortunatly I get following exception when I click on my commandLink 
`Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHo‌​lder.java:166)`

Comment: `com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]`

Comment: `<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Looks like your JSF state management is messed up. The additional maven dependency on JSF API also doesn't look good. Your stack trace namely hints that you're using JBoss server which already ships with JSF API bundled. Those duplicate JSF API libraries in runtime classpath (one from JBoss itself and another from Maven in WAR) might have conflicted each other somehow. Get rid of that Maven dependency, just a compile-only dependency on Java EE ought to be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for you advice. I removed jsf-api and used jboss-jsf-api with scope = provided.

Comment: Nevertheless - its still not working :-/ 
Same exception
Another problem is that when I login (SpringSecurity) and I force an exception the loginform of my template is rendered even it included `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{authenticationBean.user!=null}"`.
When I return to index.xhtml the loginform is not displayed anymore what is the correct behaivor when i am loggedin.
All my backing beans are session scoped - is it possible that there is a problem with the sessions on errorpages?
BR

Comment: Oh, you're using Spring Security. That's the missing key. The page in question is a restricted page, right? That would probably explain everything. Try once again on a public page to exclude more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58333/discussion-between-dandiesel-and-balusc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141963/mojarra-2-1-6-not-working-as-expected-with-omnifaces-fullajaxexceptionhandler

Comment: You're using Mojarra 2.2.6, which is not prehistoric.

Comment: Yeah but this excactly the same exception

Comment: Replacing the content of "RenderErrorPageView" Method with ` String viewId = getViewIdAndPrepareParamsIfNecessary(context,
      errorPageLocation);
     ViewHandler viewHandler = context.getApplication().getViewHandler();
     String actionURL = viewHandler.getRedirectURL(context, viewId,
      null, false);
     context.getExternalContext().redirect(actionURL);`
Solved the problem - Hmm-....

Comment: You're sending a HTTP redirect instead of rendering the view. This is not conform standard servlet spec and does not work for error pages in `/WEB-INF`.

Comment: Ok - I found out that If i Comment out this Line 
`request.removeAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_ERROR_EXCEPTION);`
The exception does not occure but commandLink still does not work